# Is there any reason to use UEFI with Windows 10?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, windows-10

Or another way of putting it, will I be impacted in any way if I use legacy BIOS mode with Windows 10?

I'm not fond of having a new complex software layer underneath my OS especially with the recent UEFI malware revelations.

Using legacy bios also lets you make use of encryption software like Truecrypt.

Comment: If you use Secure Boot you are not vulnerable to those attacks though and Windows has FDS encryption

Comment: That's only a digital signature protection. That is hardly secure.

Comment: So I guess you don't trust SSL/TLS either.

Comment: "I'm not fond of having a new complex software layer" -- BIOS emulation is a complex software layer running on top of your UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 1):

1. UEFI supports [Secure Boot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824987.aspx) (and MBR doesn't).
2. It's immune to MBR viruses, since BIOS is not directly loading the OS, and delegated EFI firmware to do that.
3. GPT disks support up to 128 primary partitions, while MBR supports up to 4 primary partitions or 3 primary and 1 extended partition, split in up to 128 logical partitions .
4. GPT disks have reserved space for hidden services and metadata (e.g. MSR partition).

If you don't care about mentioned advantages, so you simply don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

There are reasons for and against and they have not really changed since Win8.

You can better use GPT which allows more flexible partitioning.
It might be faster.
It seems that sometimes - if you can choose - the installed UEFI has more ootions.

FastBoot might be nice for you, in some situations, primarily when only using Windows and no dual-boot.
SecureBoot has imho not really proven secure as it is rather easy to workaround it when having physical access - and physical access is pretty much the only scenario where SecureBoot would make a change. You might activate it for a small additional security boost but it ain't really kicking it.

I'm going with UEFI because I like to use GPT without a hassle and it seems that "Legacy BIOS" will die anyway.

My advice: Lookup any list of differences between BIOS and UEFI and make up your mind yourself what is pro and what con ;-)

Comment: @Andy In what case does it help when the attacker has no physical access? This would mean he had digital access, meaning he already got the software on the device. This can only be done (without physical access) via the OS - in which case SecureBoot cannot do much or via exploiting UEFI bugs in which case SecureBoot is probably not of much help either as the attacker most likely will be able to disable it. -- Am I missing something?

Comment: @Andy Surely there is the possibiltiy that the OS is hacked and the attacker wants to place his code deep down in the OS's firmware etc. In this case it helps - as you say - "pretty well". But: Given the attacker has come so far, I doubt he could not take a few strides extra to workaround that limitation. I said "pretty much the only scenario" as it actually isnt the only one but virtually is. There are not many scenarios left and those are most likely not to affect consumers anyway. As I said: A bit more security but not "a kicker"

Comment: It helps from getting a rootkit, which can be harder to remove and could infect other oses installed.  Access is not a binary thing, either the hacker has it or he does it.  Often the first success is getting limited access, and the using other exploits to gain more access.  SecureBoot isn't even a feature of Windows, its part of UEFI.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/22/protecting-the-pre-os-environment-with-uefi.aspx

Comment: @Andy I know it is, again, that's why I said "mostly" as such rootkits are rare. I dont mean it's binary, but imagine a hacker having gained the rights to write to the firmware files or drivers: In most cases this is enough. And if not  well he most likely has Admin/Root rights then anyway and will find away around that SecureBoot limitation. Also SecureBoot relies on CAs (actually MS with Verisign which got hacked multiple times. Both.). So even worse: It suggests security but actually might just be secure.

Comment: @Andy And also though it aint "a feature of Windows" but is "part of UEFI" - it's not because the others wanted it but because MS does. MS is the CA in most cases. Arguing that it is in the UEFI specification is just ignoring who wrote that piece of paper. But I didn't want to turn this into a pro/con on SecureBoot. I never said that it wont add a bit of security - but I will say that there's a) a big trade of in felxibilty and b) it only applies in really rare scenarios where the hacker is really skilled anyway - and probably can work around that limitation

Comment: "that's why I said "mostly" as such rootkits are rare"  not sure where you get that idea, but its false.  And installing a virus into firmware is much harder to remove, even a reformat wouldn't get rid of it.  The same reason a hacker would want to infect hard drive firmware.  If secureboot is enabled you can't get around it, that's the point.  I think you need to read up on how certificates work as well.  Its highly unlikely a compromised key will end up in secure boot.

Comment: Again, you are wrong.  MS didn't come up with it themselves and certainly aren't the only ones that are interested.  http://www.uefi.org/members  note that apple and redhat are in that quite lengthy list.  MS required it to be Windows certified at some point, but even then it can still be disabled.  MS isn't even a CA, they use existing CAs just like everyone else.  They aren't creating self signed certs to be used in the list.

Comment: @Andy What you are writing is how rootkits work. But this does not support your claim that they are not rare. I know that rootkits are very hard to remove and that SecureBoot would protrct againsy them (see my 2nd comment) - but still: Rootkits make out a very small part in the malware "share" and it is not really likely to get one. That's all I'm saying. If SecureBoot is installed you simply need to go to more hassle. What I mean with "get around it" is that the attacker might try to achieve what he needs without a rootkit as - again - a standard virus in *most* cases can do enough.

Comment: @Andy Also he might try to exploit a bug in UEFI it self (which happened). -- I did not claim that MS came up with it by themselves only. I only claim thay they are one of the biggest supporters. Again: Just because they wrote the paper together and RedHat is also a member it does not mean that SecureBoot is something that RedHat really supports. It only says that they took part. The same way when in a parliament 99/100 voted yes you cannpt say that everyone supported it - even the guy who voted no - just because he is a member.

Comment: @Andy  MS requires OEMs to default to SecureBoot and, with Win10, giving the option to disable it is even optional. -- Anyway, part of the root CAs are afaik hosted by Verisign which got compromised fairly often. Another way, to get around SecBoot. -- So all I'm saying is: a) It's unlikely that it will save you in your specific case as rootkits are *rare* though powerful b) It's quite a hassle, depending on what u do c) It *might* be compromised anyway. - c) Is **really** a *might*. But for sure, UEFI *might* be compromised too...

Comment: "But this does not support your claim that they are not rare. I know that rootkits are very hard to remove and that SecureBoot would protrct againsy them (see my 2nd comment) - but still: Rootkits make out a very small part in the malware "share" and it is not really likely to get one. That's all I'm saying"  They aren't rare; if you believe they are, I don't know what to tell you, but its delusional to think they aren't out in the wild and there's a risk of getting one.

Comment: "If SecureBoot is installed you simply need to go to more hassle. What I mean with "get around it" is that the attacker might try to achieve what he needs without a rootkit as - again - a standard virus in most cases can do enough"  Uh, ya, then that shows that secure boot works, if it blocks a hacker from installing a rootkit, which is what it was designed to do.  Please stop with the red herring argument that it doesn't protect against other viruses, as that's not what it was designed to protect against. One thing it does help with those is viruses which could previously

Comment: disable your AV software because it gets into the pre-boot code.  "I did not claim that MS came up with it by themselves only. I only claim that they are one of the biggest supporters"  There are a bunch of supporters, where do you get that they're even the biggest?  Apple isn't big?  Dell isn't?  Acer isn't?  Please.  RedHat contributed, this isn't like your congress example, RedHat didn't have to become a member at all, yet they support SB in Fedora 18.

Comment: "MS requires OEMs to default to SecureBoot and, with Win10, giving the option to disable it is even optional."  Stop with the weasel words.  You tried implying MS forced this on everyone, and when you got called out said "oh i meant they are the biggest supporter."  And now you're trying to imply the option to disable in the bios is gone, which its not. Yes, MS might require it on to install W10, just like they require a certain minimum of memory, HD space, etc.  But the option to disable will still be there.  You can choose to met the min specs and run w10, or not, but nothing wrong with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26629/discussion-between-andy-and-larkey).

Comment: If you think SecureBoot cannot prevent remote access comprosing the boot sector of your pc, which is the entire point of Secure Boot, then you know nothing about SecureBoot.  If Apple supported Secure Boot, the current bug that can compromised the Apple firmware using a remote exploit, and be spread by Thunderbolt wouldn't even be a concern.

Comment: That's not what I wrote and what I think. I think that it's just rather unlikely to catch a virus like that as most are more trivial. -- And then there are certainly drawbacks to SecureBoot - some find them more severe than others. All I am saying is that in many cases SecureBoot will not help (as the things it tries to secure are not attacked) but in any case you might feel the drawbacks. Then there's the problem with physical access in which case you virtually always can do anything. And then there's the point that since Win10 it is not required to be able to disable SecureBoot.

Comment: I do *not in any way* doubt it would help against remote attacks that go 'that deep'. But I doubt that those attacks are that frequent. Especially as those viruses are most probably targeted at systems with a "crazy" level of security anyway. If your systems is by all means really secure you really wouldlike to check out SecureBoot for your system to harden. But: Most people really won't be affected. It's the same for a tresor-linux-kernel: It's useful for additional security but has quite a tradeoff. But it's good it exists.